# Detailed reputation report?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-audit, personal-statistics

Is there a way to see a detailed report of how I collected my reputation on a specific site, grouped by the way of achievement? E.g.

```
+100 from being a network user
+450 from upvoted questions
+300 from upvoted answers
-80 from downvotes
+45 from accepted answers
-200 from bounties
```

Ideally I would also like to be able to drop down each section to see the specific questions / answers.

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense to separate votes into the categories you have listed. The repcap means that the order that you received the votes will determine which ones got rep and which didn't.

Comment: You could parse the `/reputation` text output and build that report yourself.